# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/blackbird/ser/ToBooleanFunction

Tags: java, jackson, pom.xml, java-17, jackson-modules

I am getting this error trying to upgrade from Java 11 to 17.

I confirmed that the ToBooleanFunction exists in the 2.15.2 version, as well as some other versions I've tried. I also confirmed that the library is in the class path.

Here are the relevant parts of my pom file. Appreciate any input.

```
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-module-blackbird</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
           </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. You could try Jackson version 2.13.5. In my case it works well.